# Automatic rotation and crop of images based on detetction reference marks

Tags: r, image, detection

I have developed a framework in R to automatically measure vegetation structure variables from whiteboard photos taken on grasslands for ecological related studies. Until now we have preprocessed the images by hand, however now we need to automatise the rotation and cropping of the images.

The idea is the following: Use reference marks on the whiteboard, and detect these markings to rotate and crop the [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cywq.jpg) photographs. I need help to detect the reference markings. After knowing the position of reference markings (centroids) we can calculate the coordinates/pixels where to crops the image. In the end, we want to get a picture like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvK6Y.jpg).

We can use some special colour for the markings, but these can be obstructed by the vegetation. The bottom of the whiteboard is always obstructed, the cropped part (without the reference markings) should be 25×100 cm.

Possibly edge detection can be a solution. I'm familiar with only with R programming.